# How to grab the first instance of a keyword and the line below it for Jira Service Management automation

Tags: java, regex, jira

I am using Jira Service Desk automation and need to use regex for *just the first instance* of a keyword called "Traceback:" including the next line in braces `{}`, for instance:

```
{Traceback:
TypeError : stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null }
bytes, not str
Traceback:
 File "/Applications/modules/lon_project/libern/runtime_utils.py", line 181, in run return_value = self.target()
```

I've been trying to use the following regex:

```
{{issue.description.match("(Traceback:[\s\n\r]\*[^\r\n].*)")}}
```

which doesn't match.

Related, could you explain how to escape forward and backslashes in Jira regex?

Comment: I checked and it is meant to be Java based regex. The curly brackets/mustache is Jira format. I believe this is more of a Jira syntax question that uses a limited number of Java regex. I'm asking for help in grabbing just the first instance of "Traceback:" and the line immediately below it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Unfortunately, it doesnt seem to be working and so I believe this is more of a Jira automation question. Note that I've changed to title to reflect a Jira question.

Comment: `[\\s\n\r]*`....

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
{{issue.description.match("Traceback:([\s\n\r]*[^\r\n].*)")}}
```

I moved the capture group parentheses, so the text 'Traceback' was found once.